# How can I do a LESS in Excel?

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula, libreoffice, vba

I have two Excel columns, one with 7000 rows, one with 600.

For each of the 600, if it exists in the 7000, I would like it removed from the list. So, assuming 200 of my 600 questions are contained in the 7000, I would be left with a column containing 400. I believe this would be expressed as A / B, a being the list of 600 sentences, B being the 7000.

I'm sure there is an easy way of doing this, but I am unfamiliar with Excel. I am open to any language or tool.

Comment: You can use MATCH() for this.

Comment: @TimWilliams I have been looking at this function, but I can't figure out how it would print the correct value in a third column. Would you be able to elaborate a little bit please? :)

Comment: What was the purpose of the LibreOffice tag? Were you just throwing mud at a wall to see what would stick?

Comment: @Jeeped No, it is a .file that can be opened by both programs. I don't mind for which the solution is in. Thanks for your response :)

Comment: It is possible to do this with formulas rather than a macro, although it's fairly involved.  There's an explanation & example file in [this OpenOffice forum thread](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=75&t=38056)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If column **A** is the short list and column **B** is the long list then try this macro:

```
Sub PurgeAList()
    Dim rA As Range, rB As Range, nA As Long, nB As Long
    Dim rc As Long, i As Long, v As Variant

    rc = Rows.Count
    nA = Cells(rc, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    nB = Cells(rc, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rA = Range("A1:A" & nA)
    Set rB = Range("B1:B" & nB)

    For i = nA To 1 Step -1
        v = Cells(i, "A").Value
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rB, v) > 0 Then
            Cells(i, "A").Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

It will remove items from the short list that appear in the long list.

Answer (score 0):

If your 600 questions are in A1:A600 and your 7000 are in D1:D7000 then in B1 enter:

```
=COUNTIF($D$1:$D$7000,A1)
```

and fill down.
Questions not in the larger list will have 0 in that column